# OpenCart 3.0.3.8 upgrade to 4.0.1.1

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I recently upgraded an old store from 2.0.1.1 to 3.0.3.8 but to comply with PHP8 I need to upgrade again from 3.0.3.8 to 4.x. My question stems because I was able to successfully install the new 4.0.1.1 storefront, but I am no longer able to access my admin panel. Attempting to login to my admin will always give me the error that the account does not exist.

I have double checked the config.php files in both my root & admin folders and the database information stored there is correct. Also, I checked my actual database to make sure the user accounts weren't deleted in the upgrade and they were not.

I don't see a lot of documentation about the upgrade process to a 4.x OpenCart storefront so I am coming here in hopes someone has been brave enough to attempt this upgrade that may be able to point me in the right direction. Some tips and tricks would be greatly welcomes because I imagine this is just the first of many moles I am going to need to whack.

Let me know if any code would be needed/handy, but keep in mind this install is basically all stock barebones at this point because I haven't even tried to activate my custom theme yet (mostly because I can't access the admin to activate it).

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by upgrading to the OpenCart 3.x.x_Maintenace branch, instead of OpenCart 4.x.x version, as it is also PHP8 compliant and much more stable.

For anyone with similar issues, they can refer this [link](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/tree/3.0.x.x_Maintenance).